# Retrieve custom variable from PayPal Button in Django

Tags: django, paypal-ipn

Hi I have a django app hosted on Heroku.

I have a view with the paypal button, which is working and sends me back to my success url. But on the success url I want to display/use my custom variable.

I tried some solutions from StackOverflow already, but I can not fix it by myself.

**URLS**

```
path('match/<int:pk>', MatchDetail, name='match-detail'),
path('match_paid/', MatchPaid, name='match-paid'),
```

**MatchDetail - PayPalButton**

The form looks like this:

```
  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="custom" value="{{match.id}}">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/de_DE/DE/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Jetzt einfach, schnell und sicher online bezahlen – mit PayPal.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
  </form>
```

In PayPal I have set the custom variables of my button to:

```
custom=custom  # What is most likely wrong.
```

Now I want the custom variable to be print in the return URL `'match_paid/'`.
Tried  `{{custom}}, {{request.custom}}` etc.

Comment: But this will - as far as I know - use a `POST` parameter, so this will be lost when the URL returns. Where did you specify the return URL? Perhaps you can use `GET` parameters, although a user can easily strip these away.

Comment: Well, how should I do it? I thought my custom variable is sent to PayPal and then I need to retrieve it after the actual payment to update my db. But I don't know how to setup up PayPal itself so it send the variable back and also how to retrieve it.

Comment: Well what if you use `<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin//webscr?custom={{match.id}}>`, does it return the `custom`?